# Smooth scroll in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does Visual studio code have smooth scroll ?

If yes please help me.

It would be nice to scroll through long codes with smoother effect.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

> // Controls if the editor will scroll using an animation

```
  "editor.smoothScrolling": false,
```

> // Enable this workaround if scrolling is no longer smooth after
> restoring a minimized VS Code window. This is a workaround for an
> issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13612) where
> scrolling starts to lag on devices with precision trackpads like the
> Surface devices from Microsoft. Enabling this workaround can result in
> a little bit of layout flickering after restoring the window from
> minimized state but is otherwise harmless.

```
  "window.smoothScrollingWorkaround": false
```

Those are the **defaults**, set to `true` for smooth scrolling (second setting only if you need it).

---

Also see [smooth scrolling in lists and trees: v1.46 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#smooth-scrolling-for-lists-and-trees) adds this setting:

`workbench.list.smoothScrolling` for the explorer, etc.

### Update November 2020

VS Code has been updated and its settings UI also has changed. So to enable smooth scrolling in VS Code. Go to settings and just search smooth you can just enable this setting to enable smooth scrolling.
[image]

Comment: a lot of these IDEs make some questionable default setting choices.
do they really think most computers nowadays are so resource-limited that they can't support smooth scrolling to default it to off?

Comment: It is exactly the same. The scroll is faster than "Speedy Gonzales" yet

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for this and found out that they do have an inbuilt setting for this in vscode.

Under *Settings* > In the search bar, search for "*scroll*" > [Editor: Smooth Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFugx.png)